# How can we find the leading principal minors of a non-square $m \times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

All my research has shown that the leading principal of order $k$ of an $ n \times n$ matrix is obtained by deleting the last $n-k$ rows and their corresponding columns.

What if we have a non-square, $m \times n$ matrix? How do we find the leading principal minors then?

Comment: If [Wikipedia is to be believed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Other_applications) (and it's usually pretty reliable for mathematics), then the $k$th leading principal minor is obtained by deleting the $m-k$ last rows and $n-k$ last columns.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [Wikipedia is to be believed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Other_applications) (and it's usually pretty reliable for mathematics), then the $k$th leading principal minor is obtained by deleting the $m-k$ last rows and $n-k$ last columns.